# Deleting all of my questions?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Delete my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/delete-my-account)

How can I delete my account and all of my questions on StackOverFlow?

Comment: Dupe of... list is too long, try here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=delete+account

Comment: While your account can be deleted (see the duplicate and the answers below) your questions will remain see the cc-wiki license at the foot of every page - http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5/

Comment: @ChrisF: Accounts can be completely destroyed. There are two types of deletion: Deletion, and Destruction. The first leaves the good material behind for the benefit of others, the second completely incinerates everything in a wicked-awesome sort of way.

Comment: @khat - I didn't know that. I'll leave my comment here as a record of this difference.

Comment: @khat - Have you tried Destructing User #1?  I believe it's sort of a rite of passage for mods, right?

Comment: @Pollyanna: I have heard of those who tried, but legions of weeping ponies haunt your dreams during the process, and that would just be unbearable.

Comment: @ChrisD - it's important to note that the data exists in old data dumps though.  Given that it's CC-Wiki, Jeff can't control all the data everywhere it exists, it can only be deleted locally.  But there have even been cases of high-profile (and prolific!) users taking their ball and going home too...  (and, IIRC, one case of someone leaving then saying, "Uh, guys, I changed my mind - can I come back please?!" leading to quite the effort to undo a delete...)

Comment: @khat - it's going to take me a long time to get used to your name change... Weren't your accounts previously associated?  Zounds!

Comment: @Pollyanna - who is this "ChrisD" to whom you speak?

Comment: @Pollyanna: Meta is a terrible island of lowly-eques - I have no associations here. @ChrisF, "ChrisD" is your sequential-grandfather, of course.

Comment: I deleted what I could.  If there's more than 1 answer, I can't delete my question.

Comment: @ChrisF - Shush, I'm trying to have a conversation with one of your multiple personalities.  Let ChrisD have control for a moment please.

Comment: @ChrisF, Only worry when you see ChrisZ or ChrisXXX.

Answer (score 1):

Email team@stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can request that a diamond-moderator destroy your account. This may require some internal-dialog amongst the moderators before this action is *actually* taken though as it's not a very common practice and may have some fine-rules that govern the action in some way.

Comment: To request a diamond moderator destroy your account, flag one of your questions for moderator attention and make the request in that request box.

Comment: +1@Pollyanna: Jeff made a good suggestion too; edit your profile to say "Please delete me," just as an extra measure to determining your ownership.

Comment: Actually, that's a good idea.